# Automatically convert Spring JPA Entity OneToMany to List<ID> in DTO and back (ModelMapper)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

Animal.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Animal implements MyEntityInterface {
    public enum Sex {MALE, FEMALE}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private Sex sex;
    private boolean castrated;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Symptom> symptoms;
}
```

AnimalDTO.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AnimalDTO implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Animal.Sex sex;
    private boolean castrated;

    private List<Long> symptoms;
}
```

I wish for a list of Symptoms to be automatically mapped to a list of ID's. This could be achieved in many ways, such as creating a TypeMap, creating a Converter or even just by creating a method in AnimalDTO.java:

```
public void setSymptoms(List<Symptom> symptoms) {
    if (symptoms != null)
        this.symptoms = symptoms.stream().map(s -> s.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But now imagine it's not only Symptoms, but 50 other fields too. That's a lot of code for the same functionality. And then, it's not only Animal to AnimalDTO, but another 30 different classes with their respective DTOs too.

Also, that still leaves the way back open. From ID to entity. This can (in theory) be achieved easily with the following pseudocode:

```
List<EntityMemberField.class> list;
for (var entityid : listOfEntityIDsOfDto) {
    Object persistedObject = entityManager.find(EntityMemberField.class, entityid);
    list.add(persistedObject);
}
...
ModelMapperDestination.setField(list);
```

This is the same for absolutely every Entity/DTO and should automatically happen for every Entity relationship where the Entity implements MyEntityInterface.

An idea how I could achieve that would be overriding MappingEngineImpl.java from ModelMapper which I register as a Spring Service and inject the EntityManager into, but how could I get ModelMapper to use mine? Or is there maybe an easier way?

The goal is to have a fairly automated conversion from Spring Entities to their corresponding DTO by... just calling `modelMapper.map(entity, EntityDTO.class);`